# Busca com múltiplos valores LIKE com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde, faço uma busca utilizando LIKE com o laravel em uma tabela, porém esta busca pode necessitar de vários valores ex: %joão% %josé%, etc. porém não estou encontrando uma maneira de fazer essa busca com vários valores no Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da mesma forma que for fazer com `where`, só que usando o `orWhere` isso em um caso de condição lógica `or`,  por exemplo:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('name_1', 'like', '%thi%')
                    ->orWhere('name_2', 'like', '%John%')
                    ->get();
```

A única diferença é o fato de você usar o o `orWhere`.

**Referencia:** 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses